# Is Connect-ExchangeOnline cmdlet uses basic auth?

Tags: powershell, exchangeonline, office365

Am trying to connect Exchange Online using Connect-ExchangeOnline. But, it seems require basic authentication. Is it possible to use this cmdlet without basic auth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect-ExchangeOnline uses modern auth in O365 end. However it require basic authentication in the client side.

Basic authentication header is required to transport the session’s OAuth token, since the client-side WinRM implementation has no support for OAuth.

For more info: https://o365reports.com/2019/12/11/connect-exchange-online-powershell-without-basic-authentication/

Comment: Thanks. can you share the doc for this?

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to the following article:
https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2250084-can-t-connect-to-exchange-online-mfa-without-basic-auth